# Is there a way to modify a jar with a wrong manifest using the maven-bundle-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jar, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I have an OSGI project, one of the dependencies is a jar with a wrong manifest value (wrong Bundle-NativeCode), so I get a null pointer exception when trying to install the plugin I build. Is there a way for me to modify the manifest of that dependency with the maven-bundle-plugin somehow?

I know the problem is the manifest because I modified the jar on my local .m2 repository, fixed the manifest and it works fine, but that is not reproducible and should be fixed at build time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it will be better to change this library to another, that don't have this bug or contact with company/developer and raise a bug.
But if you really need to use it,  the only idea that comes to your mind is to create 2 projects. One it will be own maven plugin to unpack, fix and pack this dependency. And next one that will have only the broken dependency and as result will have fixed package.
In your project insted of orginal libraty, you need to add fixed package.